# Simple Automation studio question

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, automationstudio

Hi can anyone assist with some basic automation studio questions?

I am new to Marketing Cloud but simply want to trigger an automated email send to those who do not open an email in 7 days time.

i cant seem to find anything under the 'filter' parameter and not sure where to create this.

thanks
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way would be to create a filter using measures and an automation to run a user initiated send daily.

1. Create a measure on the "Not Open" data source.
2. Create this filter using "job delivered date" and "Job ID" "Email Name" or some other identifier to ensure this does not collect ALL emails that did not open.
3. Create a User-Initiated send using the filter you created as the 'recipients'
4. Go into automation studio and create a new automation
5. Set the user-initiated send as the only item in this automation
6. Schedule it to run daily at whatever time you feel appropriate.

This will now daily send out to any people that did not open your specific email in the last 7 days.

Comment: Thanks for this - i already use options 1-4 for our solus email sends that we need to return to to dictate the non opens. I will though give options 5/6 a run  as at least this may give me the opportunity to prepare the send in advance.

Comment: Looking again i need to begin the automation with an 'event' do you know which option under that is defined as 'user initiated' send? thanks again

Comment: you can schedule the automation, you do not need to have it run as a triggered automation. When you go to "create automation" there will be the option for "Scheduled Automation" or "Triggered Automation".

Comment: Excellent - gave it a go and running a test now. thanks again. I have a couple of questions

 Is it possible to include the first send within the automation itself?

If i wanted to run two different scenarios, one email send to non opens and one email to those who did not - would i need to run 2 different filters to achieve that?

Comment: you could include the first send within the automation, but it would likely require you to add a filter to the list based on some sort of a flag in the data. In the email you would upsert this flag to the Data Extension on send so it would not send to them again next time the automation is run. For question 2, yes you would need two different filters and user-intiated sends - but both can be in same automation.

Comment: @Craig Fish - If this solved your issue, please make sure to mark it as correct so others can find the solution if they experience your same problem.

Comment: I can confirm this works perfectly. Do let me know if there are any online resources that can help me extend this automation further